# How to identify multiple intersecting polygons in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, geometry, polygon, intersection, overlap

I'm trying to identify overlapping/intersecting polygons. The techniques I have found only compare two polygons at a time. I have tens-of-thousands of cells in a dataset, and in each one there are 2-20 polygons, each described by x-y coordinates. I want to find the overlapping polygons in each cell. Looping between every pair to check for an intersection is very slow, so I want to ask...

Is there a way to compare all polygons at the same time and extract the IDs of those that are overlapping?

Here is a simple example of a single entry from the dataset:

```
shapes = cell(4,2);
shapes{1,1} = 'poly1';
shapes{2,1} = 'poly2';
shapes{3,1} = 'poly3';
shapes{4,1} = 'poly4';
shapes{1,2} = [1, 3, 3; 1, 1, 3]';
shapes{2,2} = [2, 4, 2; 2, 2, 5]';
shapes{3,2} = [4, 5, 5, 4; 3, 3, 5, 5]';
shapes{4,2} = [1, 3, 3, 1; 4, 4, 6, 6]';
```

This example contains these 4 polygons:

[image: The example dataset contains these 4 polygons]

This plot was made with separate 'polyshape' objects, but that doesn't mean I need to use this kind of object in the solution.

The output I would like is a record of each overlapping pair:

```
result =
  2×2 cell array
    {'poly1'}    {'poly2'}
    {'poly2'}    {'poly4'}
```

P.S. My current method is to loop through each pair and use the poly2mask function on each polygon of the pair. Then use the & operator to add the binary masks together. This produces a logical array of 1's where there is any overlap.

P.P.S. The actual polygons I am looking at are all annular sectors, therefore they are not all convex

[image: Annular sector]

Comment: Are all of your polygons convex?

Comment: No, they are actually annular sectors, I will update the question.

Comment: Is the concave/convex question important because they could have multiple areas of overlap? If that was going to be a big issue in the solution then I could potentially adapt the polygons to be circular segments, which would be concave, but I would rather keep them as they are.

Comment: Looping is not slow, and you need to compare each pair anyhow, so it remains O(n^2) in the number of polygons within the cell. What is slow is repeatedly converting polygons to masks. You convert each polygon multiple times, it seems from your description. But using this mask is not precise anyway. Use the right tool: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.intersect.html

Comment: @beaker: Here is a counter-example for your method: two rectangles, forming a cross. They each are polygons with 4 vertices, they intersect, and none of the vertices is inside the other polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I followed @CrisLuengo 's advice and looked more into using the 'polyshape' function and I think I've come up with a solution that is much faster than before - I'll add it the answers

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're right! :) I thought I had all of the cases covered. Rats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that makes use of 'polyshape' vectors and avoids making all those pairwise comparisons in extra loops (although I don't know how the 'overlap' function works).

```
% Set up empty vector to hold the different shapes
polyvec = [];

% Loop all shapes and combine into polyshape vector
for ii = 1 : size(shapes, 1)

    poly = polyshape(shapes{ii,2}(:,1), shapes{ii,2}(:,2));

    % When you combine polyshape objects together the you get 
    % a vector that is of the polyshape object type
    polyvec = [polyvec, poly];

end

% Use the overlap function to compute a symmetric binary matrix 
% of which polygons in the polygon vector overlap. 
interMatSym = overlaps(polyvec);

% I only need the upper triangle of the symmetric interaction 
% matrix and all polygons overlap with themselves so use 'triu'
interMat = triu(overlaps(polyvec), 1);

% Find the coordinates of the overlap in the interaction matrix
[x, y] = find(interMat);

% Save the result
result = [shapes(x,1), shapes(y,1)];

result =
  2×2 cell array
    {'poly1'}    {'poly2'}
    {'poly2'}    {'poly4'}
```

If there is a way to create a polyshpae vector any more efficiently then I'd love to know!

Comment: `overlaps` is even better than `intersect`. Awesome! The algorithm (I presume) looks for intersecting vertices. This is what `intersect` also does, but finding the intersection of two polygons requires finding all points at which vertices intersect, and building a new polygon. `overlaps` will just return true as soon as one pair of intersecting vertices is found.